# COM Word Selection TypeText with line break

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

how can I  insert a line break via

```
oWord.Selection.TypeText("\r\n")
```

I don't want to use oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph or so. It has to be TypeText and it has to be as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it

```
oWord.Selection.TypeText("Hello\r\nWorld".Replace("\r\n", char.ConvertFromUtf32(11)));
```